# Dell latitude 5590 fan noise and battery issue

Tags: laptop, battery, fan, dell-latitude

I just bought a 'Like New' Dell Latitude 5590 laptop. I ran an initial diagnostics when I bought it, and everything seemed good.

After a full battery charging, I realize that the battery can't last more than 2 hours which is very low. the battery is `68 WHr 4-Cell`

The fan makes some noise!! sometimes it starts making a lot of noise for a good amount of time!!

What do you think about these two problems, is it normal or not for this `Dell Latitude 5590 I7 8th gen 16G RAM and 500G SSD`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like "as new" is dishonest or there is malware on the system. The first thing to do would be to check the fully charged capacity /health of the battery - if its less then about 95% of new capacity I dont think it can be considered "as new" (and I've returned a laptop on that basis). If its < 80% the battery is considered end of life.

You did not advise your OS, but if its Windows 10 you can generate a report by running the following command in a cmd box launched as administrator, then use a web browser to read the resulting report:

```
  powercfg /batteryreport /output "C:\path\to\batteryinfo.html
```

Another thing to check is self discharge - if you fully charge the laptop then turn it off overnight how much charge does it lose? If a cell is damaged, it could explain heat buildup and short runtime.

The second thing to look at is the CPU utilization. It sounds like there might be something eating up all the available CPU - this will drain the battery fast and cause a lot of heat which will cause the fan to be on. Look at task manager to see cpu utiluzation and processes and run av and anti-malware across the system.

Also, look at power profiles. The system will perform more responsively but drain a lot more resources if the power profile is set to performance as opposed to a more balanced mode.

Lastly, try look into the fan grate and see if there is lint blocking the airflow.

Answer (score 1):

Fans are loud when the system is generating more heat.

The system generates more heat when it is under greater load.

Greater load also requires more energy, which increases drain on the battery.

What you have described is a computer that is working hard. If you haven't installed anything on it yet, then you should start by performing a clean installation of your desired OS and allow that to patch completely.

Everything else is just guesses. Others have suggested malware, which is definitely possible, but you have not given us sufficient information to tell that.

In order to give a more specific answer you must first perform more analysis of the system and give us more information.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to run F12 diagnostic and everything is ok. The problem is the fan starts spinning  fast  and stops from time to time when no program is running

Comment: You must understand it is not when no program is running, it is when no program you SEE is running. Your computer is always running programs. An Operating System is just a big collection of programs. You have not described any hardware faults, and the F12 tests are just for hardware diagnostics and will not tell you about any software problems.

Comment: How can I check if there is any software than is making my fan spinning fast ?

Comment: Start by using the correct and more accurate terms. No software is directly making your fans spin fast. There isn't a measurement of "how fast will this program make my fans spin" except for tools that monitor fan speed. You are looking for processes that are using a large amount of system resources. On Windows you find this in the Task Manager, to start with.